# Git post-receive hook acts differently to shell

Tags: git, deployment, hook

I'm trying to setup a git repo on my live server to automatically update a subdomain on receive. Using this guide http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto.

**hooks/post-receive**

```
#!/bin/sh
pwd
git checkout -f
```

**config**

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        worktree = /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/staging/httpdocs
[receive]
        denycurrentbranch = ignore
```

If I run git *checkout -f* in /var/git/domain.com.git/ it works, the subdomain is updated.
However, when I push I get the  following output:

```
/var/git/domain.com.git
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

I'm not sure why this works in the shell, but not in the hook. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions on the worktree do not allow it to be read which causes the `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree` error.

Answer (score 1):

add `cd /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/staging/httpdocs` to your post-recieve hook.

Comment: This does not work in the hook or in shell.
Because /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/staging/httpdocs has not .git folder.

It did however throw a permission denied error, because my ssh user has no permissions in that folder. Which I suspect is the cause of my problems.