# Synchronize Apache with a repository

Tags: git, apache, svn, synchronization

I am going to start a new project and I am going to have an Apache with two domains (one for testing, another for stable).

I am probably going to use Git, so let's say I use Git as version control. I want to synchronize the testing subdomain with the repository - that means, when someone commits to the eventual Git server, the testing subdomain is going to run the latest commit.

What is the right way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Github, then:

https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks

You'll need a script on your server which can do a git pull when it receives a notification.

Here's more:
http://www.bram.us/2012/05/06/automatic-website-publishing-with-git-github-style/

And more:
[git / github and web server deployment configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236161/git-github-and-web-server-deployment-configuration)