# Why does `rm -rf` behave differently when used in a git post-receive hook as opposed to shell?

Tags: git, hook, sh, rm, git-post-receive

I'm using [this example on publishing a website w/ git post receive hooks](http://hayley.ws/2010/12/04/getting-jekyll-running.html).

The hook pretty much clones the bare repo into a temporary directory, and after generating the site, removes that temporary git clone.

```
#!/bin/sh
# clone a repo, generate site etc
# done generating site, remove the TMP_GIT_CLONE
rm -rf $TMP_GIT_CLONE
```

When I do the push, all the other tasks fine, but doesn't remove *all* the files.

I get the follwing errors:

```
remote: rm: <TMP_GIT_CLONE>/.git/objects/pack: Directory not empty
remote: rm: <TMP_GIT_CLONE>/.git/objects: Directory not emppty
```

...

You get the idea

However, when I invoke the `post-receive` script directly from the command line, the `rm` behaves as expected.

Why?

Note: I've looked at [Post-hook receive act's differently to shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898117/git-post-receive-hook-acts-differently-to-shell), where the asker's problem had to do with being in a bare repo instead of a work-tree.

Comment: Some ideas: you are using another version of `rm`, or another shell which has a built-in `rm` command?

Comment: I'm inclined to say that the environments are the same. `which -a rm` only returns one (logged in). It's on FreeBSD 7.2 (nearlyfreespeech). Login shell is bash. my `.bash_profile` gets executed on login, as well as with the git post receive hook

Comment: add some 'ls -a' commands after the rm to see what files are sticking around. that might give you some clues.

Comment: any file that is a directory stays around

Comment: What is your umask set to? What user owns that directory? What are the permissions on the directory you are cloning into?

Comment: Still you should check these things from the Gig script also. It might execute wita a different environment from yours (different PATH, different umask, ... in the general case even on a different host) so only checking from your interactive shell is not sufficient. (Pardon if I am stating the obvious; it is not clear from your comments whether you have done this already.)

Comment: No, need for pardon, I haven't done all these things from a non-interactive shell. I'll report back when I've checked these things out

Answer (score 1):

use

```
which rm
```

to get rm's path eg. /bin/rm

then replace it with /bin/rm to get another try.  Sometimes, it is occurs by your shell script's start scripts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you explain the reasoning behind this in more detail? My PATH works correctly, because the actual *launching* of executables work fine (e.g. `jekyll`, `rm`, etc). The thing is that `rm` seems to only be removing some files, but not all of them. It's as if the -rf options are not sticking, or the permissions are different.

Comment: It depends on your shell. For example, if you use bash and the system have some default "alias".  You could check `alias rm`. Does my solution work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you ever found a way around this, but I had the exact same problem.  I found that the /git/objects/pack directory was the one not emptying.  I suspect that whatever process is used to track files runs slower or in a different manner when you're either in ssh or post-receive.

The solutions:

One way is to manually remove those directories.  This kind of worked for me, but I didn't want to depend on that structure being the same.  I tried removing just the .git directory first.  That produced the odd behavior of complaining about non-empty directories but eventually emptying them.

A better approach is to avoid the unnecessary git files in the first place.  The answers to
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export) may provide some insight.
I replaced the 'git clone' line with:

```
mkdir -p $TMP_GIT_CLONE
git archive master --format=tar | tar -x -f - -C $TMP_GIT_CLONE
```

I think it's safe to git rid of $GIT_REPO.  Since you're in a post-receive hook, you know you're in the repo you want to clone anyway.